# heatmap using android maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am trying to build a `heatmap` using Google Maps for Android API v2. The intensity is based on the number of markers in the given area.
I have gone though http://code.google.com/p/mapex/ which is for API v1 and uses Overlays for generating the `heatmap`. I have modified the code partially to work for me via a View(I create my own custom `heatmapview` which extends view and in the `draw()`, I create those `RadialGradient` patterns).

I also found some basic info online that for API V2, we need to use `TileOverlay` and `TileProvider`, which I need help with. Seems like all the examples I see are getting the data through `UrlTileProvider`, which would not be feasible for me. I have a set of LatLng points with me and would like to use it only.

Can anyone give me some hint on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

As of a few days ago, you can now use the [Google Maps Android Heatmap Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/heatmap).  From the link:

> The Google Maps Android API Utility Library includes a heatmap
>   utility, which you can use to add one or more heatmaps to a Google map
>   in your application. Heatmaps make it easy for viewers to understand
>   the distribution and relative intensity of data points on a map.
>   Rather than placing a marker at each location, heatmaps use color to
>   represent the distribution of the data.

Comment: Thanks I know that. If you see the google's issue tracker it was me who asked for a feature like that :)